# Nextjs App Directory: MDX & Link doesn't work properly with relative links

Tags: next.js, next.js13, mdxjs

> I asked this question in the [Next.js Github Issues](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/50183), but didn't get any answer.

I copied the code from [next.js/examples/app-dir-mdx](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/app-dir-mdx). in the following [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nextjs-relative-links-bug-7wgdly) - the only additional change I made was:

- create a new markdown file in [`app/blog/test/page.mdx`](https://github.com/AnweshGangula/app-dir-mdx/blob/master/app/blog/test/page.mdx)
- customized the built-in component for the [HTML anchor tag `<a>`](https://github.com/AnweshGangula/app-dir-mdx/blob/master/mdx-components.tsx#L9) to use **`next/link`**

In the `.mdx` pages, I have added relative links to one of the other pages in the folder like below:

- `[next page](./plain-markdown)`.

I added the customization for the anchor tag in `mdx-components.tsx`. But after the customization, the links are not being redirected properly.

- when clicking on `http://localhost:3001/blog/test`, i'm being redirected to `http://localhost:3001/test`.

> Please note that the url in the DOM and even when I hover over the link show up as `http://localhost:3001/blog/test`

But what I noticed is that the url in the anchor tag href attribute is different when using app directory:

- before app directory: `<a href="/blog/plain-markdown">`
- after app directory: `<a href="./plain-markdown">`

---

**Please note that this isue is caused on when I override the default `<a>` element to use the next/link component. with the default<`> element, it works fine**

> I found [this article](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-new-link-with-extra-anchor) which states that the next/link behavior is changed in Next 13.
>
> Starting with Next.js 13, `<Link>` renders as `<a>`, so attempting to use `<a>` as a child is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [resolved in Nextjs 13.4.5](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/49521).

---

### OLD

Honestly, this looks like a bug in `next/link` when using Next 13 app router. `<Link>` component doesn't handle relative links correctly even when used in regular pages outside of mdx. I can only assume that Next MDX does some special processing of relative links, which breaks when you specify your custom link component.

In the meantime, I came up with the following workaround.

```js
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

function absolute(pathname: string, href: string) {
  if (
    href.startsWith("http://") ||
    href.startsWith("https://") ||
    href.startsWith("/")
  ) {
    return href;
  }

  const stack = pathname.split("/");
  const parts = href.split("/");
  stack.pop();

  for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (parts[i] == ".") continue;
    if (parts[i] == "..") stack.pop();
    else stack.push(parts[i]);
  }
  return stack.join("/");
}

export default function Anchor({
  href,
  children,
}: React.JSX.IntrinsicElements["a"]) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  return href !== undefined ? (
    <Link href={absolute(pathname, href)}>{children}</Link>
  ) : null;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you think this will impact the site's SEO?

Comment: @Gangula, I do not see a reason why

Comment: By the way, it looks like this bug was fixed in Next 13.4.5 - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/49521 so the above workaround should no longer be necessary.